Blender Rotate tool only rotating Origin
I try to rotate propeller so I can animate it but it just rotates the origin point help! I cant do it in edit mode cus i want to animate it spinning!
heres a video of the problem
https://youtu.be/K36_q6TdwVY
I tried alot but there was no answer for this

Okay the answer is that I had affect only on. So to fix this I went to affect only and turned them ALL off so everything was fixed.
So what you need to do is go to affect only and uncheck everything and it should work.
